# admissions (school, university) = another word for "secretary’s office"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In its "education" chapter, a pictorial ENG-GER dictionary I own translates "admissions" into "Sekretariat" (secretary’s office (of a school or university)), but several online dictionaries give me the meanings "the procedure for admitting students to study at a college, university, or school" and "the students admitted to an institution". Is the translation of my pictorial dictionary correct, maybe as a secondary meaning? I should add that there are instances where the pictorial dictionary features Indian English words, most likely because the book was produced there.

Comment: Admissions is both the process and the office within the school that handles the process.  Compare: Obstetrics, the branch of medicine and the department within the hospital concerned with it.

Comment: Google translate suggests "Admissions Department" as "Zulassungsabteilung" in German.  It's possible "Zulassung" is closer in meaning in German than "Sekretariat"

Comment: @Andrew Yes that would be a correct translation, even though _Zulassungsstelle_ is much more common and seems the closest match to me. Still not sure why this was translated as "secretary's office", but the answers and comments have confirmed my assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Admissions Office" of a school or university is responsible for determining which applicants will be permitted to attend the scool as admitted students.

People who work in schools or universities may well abbreviate "Admissions Office" to "Admissions," spelled with a capital letter. It is a usage that is perfectly acceptable in that context and milieu, but it is not the standard meaning in other contexts. I have forgotten almost every word of German I ever knew, but I greatly doubt that the typical use of "admissions" (outside the context of administering an educational institution) has anywhere close to the meaning of "Sekretariat" in German.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the practice of abbreviation and the spelling.